# Is there a way to project the clusters back into boxplot again?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, matplotlib, k-means

I have divided the data into two segments and done K-means clustering for a dataset along with normalization and PCA. Now I wanted to project the clustered plots back into boxplots to check which instances(rows) are lying in what clusters and to look for outliers.

Description: Loaded the data using pandas, Normalized using min_max_scaler and preprocessing, Applied PCA and did clustering.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import preprocessing, decomposition, cluster

# Load data from input file
X = pd.read_csv("/Users/blah blah.csv")
X.plot.scatter(x=6,y=7)

# Normalise the data
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
np_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X)
X_norm=pd.DataFrame(np_scaled, columns=X.columns)

# PCA
pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=5)
pca_model = pca.fit(X_norm)
print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)
print(pca_model.components_)
pca_array = pca_model.transform(X_norm)
X_pca = pd.DataFrame(data=pca_array, columns=['PC1','PC2','PC3','PC4','PC5'])
X_pca.plot.scatter(x=1, y=3)

# K-Means Implementation
n_clusters=5
kmeans = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, init='random', n_init=1,algorithm='full')
ac = kmeans.fit(X_pca)
print('\n..........Cluster centers............\n')
print(kmeans.cluster_centers_)
print('\n.........Cluster labels.........\n')
print(kmeans.labels_)
print('\n.............Scatter Plot K-Means......... \n')
X_pca.plot.scatter(x=1, y=3, c=kmeans.labels_, cmap='rainbow', title='K-Means Clustering')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you getting at error with your code?

Comment: no, just wondering if there is a way to do this